# Create 100% height of current viewport's height div

Tags: html, css

How Can I create a 100% height div of the current viewport size?

I know there are many resolutions around there, and I want to create a div that is high enough to cover the current size of the viewport.

Suppose the viewport is at the moment the size of one of a 1920x1080 resolution screen, but Also, someone else from a 1024x768 resolution screen wants to view the page, I want the div to be displayed 100% of the height of the viewport it is displayed on.

Is it possible with just css?

Comment: `html, body, div.class_name {height: 100%;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give 100% height to html and body, as well as to the div.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a fixed position.
Add this to the body:

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0;"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `height:100%` to the `html,body` elements.

Comment: @Alvaro He won't need that as he is using `position:fixed;`

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted though.